# Super Smoooth number

Tags: number-theory

I want to find "Super Smooth numbers" - can you advise on a method?

**Smooth number** is an integer whose prime factors are all less or equal to $B$.

Lets call number $n = (d_1 d_2 d_3 ... d_k)$ **super smooth** if all prefixes $(d_1),$ $(d_1 d_2),$ $(d_1 d_2 d_3),$ $(d_1 ..... d_k)$ are smooth numbers.

The way I have in mind is too slow on $B >1000$. This is: Firstly we check first numeral and if it is smooth we try to choose second numeral   etc. Example with $B = 3$:

1 - SMOOTH
11 -  NOT SMOOTH
12 -  SMOOTH
121 -  NOT SMOOTH
122 -  NOT SMOOTH
123 -  NOT SMOOTH
124 -  NOT SMOOTH
125 -  NOT SMOOTH
126 -  NOT SMOOTH
127 -  NOT SMOOTH
128 -  SMOOTH
1281 -  NOT SMOOTH
1282 -  NOT SMOOTH
1283 -  NOT SMOOTH
1284 -  NOT SMOOTH
1285 -  NOT SMOOTH
1286 -  NOT SMOOTH
1287 -  NOT SMOOTH
1288 -  NOT SMOOTH
1289 -  NOT SMOOTH
....

So we can get all super smooth numbers for $B = 3$:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
\text{2-digit} & 12  & 16  & 18 & 24  & 27 & 32  & 36 & 48  & 64  & 81 & 96 \\ \hline
\text{3-digit} & 128 & 162 &    & 243 &    & 324 &    & 486 & 648 &    &    \\
\end{array}
$$

Explanation example:
$648$ is supersmooth because
$6 = 2\times 3$ - smooth,
$64 = 2^6$ - smooth,
$648 = 2^3 \times 3^4$ - smooth

Comment: I think that's clearer -  I'll edit for format.

Comment: @Joffan, thank you

Comment: And if you want to format things yourself, [here's a useful guide in the Meta section](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).